# Unsatisfied dependency for com.google.firebase.functions.ContextProvider

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Trying to add firebase functions dependency `com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.3` results in the following runtime exception. Anyone knows how to fix this?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.test.nsa: com.google.firebase.components.MissingDependencyException: Unsatisfied dependency for component Component<[interface com.google.firebase.functions.ContextProvider]>{0, deps=[Dependency{anInterface=interface com.google.firebase.iid.internal.FirebaseInstanceIdInternal, required=true, direct=false}, Dependency{anInterface=interface com.google.firebase.auth.internal.InternalAuthProvider, required=false, direct=false}]}: interface com.google.firebase.iid.internal.FirebaseInstanceIdInternal
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6100)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1791)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
 Caused by: com.google.firebase.components.MissingDependencyException: Unsatisfied dependency for component Component<[interface com.google.firebase.functions.ContextProvider]>{0, deps=[Dependency{anInterface=interface com.google.firebase.iid.internal.FirebaseInstanceIdInternal, required=true, direct=false}, Dependency{anInterface=interface com.google.firebase.auth.internal.InternalAuthProvider, required=false, direct=false}]}: interface com.google.firebase.iid.internal.FirebaseInstanceIdInternal
    at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.validateDependencies(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:103)
    at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:61)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:539)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:355)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:324)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:310)
```

Comment: Have you found the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when was using Firebase along with dynamic feature modules. Managed to fix it by duplicating dependency in :app module.